# Possible reasons for Selenium (PhantomJSDriver) WebDriver not clicking a button and giving no Exception

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to click a button in a website. Problem is when the button is clicked I take a screenshot and no change in the site has been made and no exception is thrown. I've tried WebDriverWaits with no luck. I'm certain that it's that button that has to be clicked because I'm selecting it with it's id.

Maybe the page is refreshing and so is the button, if that would be the case, is there a way to prevent the website from refreshing the page? I am open to suggestions of what I can do to ensure that the button is clicked.

Currently what I'm doing to click it (not working) is:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("z_1"))).click();
```

Tried checking the displayability and clickability of the button with:

```
theButton.isDisplayed();
```

and

```
theButton.isEnabled();
```

both to return true.

I've also tried recording Actions on Firefox and transfering to the code, didn't work neither.

Comment: Could you include some of the code used to do this?

Comment: I don't have the time to include an SSCCE but I will copy the method over